# How to remove elements from the url in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a url like this which I am getting from backend

```
var myAppUrl = "https://myCompanyData.SST.com/Web150.2.0.002/SomeVal/File/File.html"
```

What I required is

`"https://myCompanyData.SST.com/Web150.2.0.002/documents/Document.asp"`

I want to remove `SomeVal/File/File.html` from myAppUrl. 
I add like

`myAppUrl+'documents/Document.asp'` and I am getting

`"https://myCompanyData.SST.com/Web150.2.0.002/SomeVal/File/File.html/documents/Document.asp`
I tried slice but somewhat I am not able to do that. How can i get that.

Comment: Post the code that you have tried

Comment: I just tried `myAppUrl.slice()`the way string works

Comment: You required `"https://myCompanyData.SST.com/Web150.2.0.002/documents/Document.asp"` but in the API URL I don't see anything like this after `...SST.com`?
Can you clarify your question.

Comment: @HarishSoni Can u see this `com/Web150.2.0.002/SomeVal/File/File.html"`

Comment: What part of the link is fixed? By that I mean what information do you have to extract from it and which parts will always be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st Option**
You need to know that [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will only work with arrays, not strings. Try using [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to create the array you need, and [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to regroup it:

```js
var myAppUrl = "https://myCompanyData.SST.com/Web150.2.0.002/SomeVal/File/File.html"

var urlSplice = myAppUrl.split('/');
urlSplice.splice(urlSplice.indexOf('SomeVal'));
urlSplice.push('documents/Document.asp');

var entireUrl = urlSplice.join('/');

console.log(entireUrl);
```

---

**2nd Option**
 Use [.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) :

```js
var myAppUrl = "https://myCompanyData.SST.com/Web150.2.0.002/SomeVal/File/File.html"

var entireUrl = myAppUrl.substring(0, myAppUrl.indexOf('SomeVal')) + 'documents/Document.asp';

console.log(entireUrl);
```

---

**3rd Option**
You can use [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace the substring you don't want:

```js
var myAppUrl = "https://myCompanyData.SST.com/Web150.2.0.002/SomeVal/File/File.html"

var baseDir = 'Web150.2.0.002';
var removableDir = myAppUrl.substring(myAppUrl.indexOf(baseDir) + baseDir.length + 1);

var newDir = 'documents/Document.asp';

var entireUrl = myAppUrl.replace(removableDir, newDir);

console.log(entireUrl);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.substr`

```js
var url = 'https://myCompanyData.SST.com/Web150.2.0.002/SomeVal/File/File.html'

var delimiter = 'Web150.2.0.002/'
// we need this to find the end index

var normalizedUrl = url.substr(0, url.indexOf(delimiter) + delimiter.length)
//_____________________________^__^ it requires start index and end index

var fullUrl = normalizedUrl + 'documents/Document.asp'

console.log(fullUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code please:

```
var myAppUrl = 'https://myCompanyData.SST.com/Web150.2.0.002/SomeVal/File/File.html';

myAppUrl = myAppUrl.split('Web150.2.0.002/')[0] + 'Web150.2.0.002/documents/Document.asp';
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove someVal/File/File.html you can use `String.prototype.replace`

```
var newURL = myAppUrl.replace("someVal/File/File.html", '')
```

To replace the last 3 parts of the adress use:

```
var newUrl = myAppUrl.replace(/(?:\/)\w*\/\w*\/\w*$/m, '').
```

If you want to replace those parts with `"documents/Document.asp"` , change `''` to  `"docuements/Document.asp"`